# Django: self symmetrical intermediate model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a symmetrical intermediate relationship between same models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    friendship = models.ManyToManyField('self', through="Friendship")
```

intermediate model:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friend1')
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friend2')
    date_befriended = models.DateField()
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I tried solving it by adding adding `through_fields=("person", "person2")` to Person(friendship), but it didn't work as expected...

**Note for future solution seekers**:`related_name` is, I'm pretty sure, obligatory in the Intermediate model to avoid errors:
`myapp.Friendship.person2: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'myapp.Friendship.person2' clashes with field name 'myapp.Person.friendship` which also occurs for Friendship(person/friend1)